# Let $X,Y \sim N(0, 1)$. Find $E[X\mid X+Y=1]$.

Tags: statistics

Assume the joint distribution for X, Y is also normal. I have no clue how to approach this problem.

Follow up question: Without knowing the joint distribution of X, Y can you still calculate it?

Comment: Note that $E[X|X+Y=1]=E[Y|X+Y=1]$, clearly.  Call the common value $E$.  Adding gives $2E=E[X+Y|X+Y=1]=1$ whence $E=\frac 12$.

Comment: You haven't told us the joint distribution.  If, for example, $X$ and $Y$ were independent, we'd know what we need.

Comment: @lulu : That's true even of $X$ and $Y$ are _not_ independent, _if_ $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ both have the same distribution, but as I said we don't have the joint distribution, and we're not even told they're jointly normal, so the word "clearly" is exaggerated.

Comment: @MichaelHardy  Agreed.  I expect that the OP intended to say that $X,Y$ were independent, but you are correct that this ought to be spelled out.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X\mid X+Y=1) & = \dfrac{\int_\Bbb R x f_{X,Y}(x,1-x)\operatorname d x}{\int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}(x,1-x)\operatorname d x} \\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\int_\Bbb R xe^{-x^2/2}e^{-(1-x)^2/2}\operatorname d x }{\int_\Bbb R e^{-x^2/2}e^{-(1-x)^2/2}\operatorname d x} \\[1ex] & =\dfrac{\Big[-\tfrac 1 2 e^{-(x^2+(1-x)^2)/2} -\sqrt\pi\operatorname {erf}(\tfrac 1 2-x)\big/2\sqrt[4]e\Big]_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty}}{\Big[-\sqrt\pi\operatorname {erf}(\tfrac 1 2-x)\big/2\sqrt[4]e\Big]_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty}} \\[1ex] & = \dfrac{1}{2}\end{align}$

Which can more easily be obtained by symmetry.

Comment: Yes, this is the hard way.  Symmetry makes it a snap.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that

- $X,Y$ are independent; or that
- $X,Y$ are jointly normal and $(X,Y)$ has the same distribution as $(Y,X)$ (a weaker assumption consistent with nonzero correlation); or that
- $(X,Y)$ has the same distribution as $(Y,X)$ (which can be true with each of them normally distributed, even if they're not jointly normal);

then
$$
\operatorname{E}(X\mid X+Y=1) = \operatorname{E}(Y\mid X+Y=1)
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{E}(X\mid X+Y=1) + \operatorname{E}(Y\mid X+Y=1) = \operatorname{E}(X+Y\mid X+Y=1) = 1,
$$
so
$$
\operatorname{E}(X\mid X+Y=1) = \frac 1 2.
$$

Comment: Someone commented using integration, he deleted it somehow but I wanted to ask if this is correct: $E(X|X+Y=1)$ will only depends on the value of Y, so $E(X|X+Y=1) = \int (1-y)dy$

Comment: @Dreamer I was mistaken, I did not normalize correctly.

Comment: No.  See my answer for how integration would work.  Symmetry is the *much* easier approach.

Comment: Thanks! Without knowing X, Y are independent or (X,Y) has the same distribution as (Y, X) can you still calculate it?